# __syncthreads not working in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I wrote simple kernel to test functionality of CUDA `__syncthreads`. In kernel I've managed to print from each thread if updated value is not visible to other threads. Ideally  no thread should print `Not visible to me` error message but some threads end up printing this message.
Here is the kernel.

```
__device__ int a=0;  
__global__ void kernel()  
{  

    isItOK=false;  
    if(threadIdx.x==0 && blockIdx.x==0)  
    {  
        atomicAdd(&a,1);  
        __threadfence();  
    }  
    __syncthreads();  
    if(atomicAdd(&a,0)==0)  
    {  
        cuPrintf("Not Visible to me\n");  
    }  

}  
int main()  
{  
    int *a;  
    cudaPrintfInit();  
    kernel<<<16,16>>>();  
    cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout,true);  
    cudaPrintfEnd();  
}
```

Please help me with this, very simple test program but still not working. Do we need some compiler flags to set ?

Comment: `__syncthreads()` is a block scope operation. You cannot synchronize between blocks in CUDA using `__syncthreads()`.

Comment: ohhh...then what should I use for synchronization across blocks?

Comment: Nothing. CUDA currently doesn't support inter-block synchronization.

Comment: But in this case why __threadfence() is not working? This function should make sure that value of a is visible to all threads but it is not helping to make this visible to all threads...

Comment: There is no guarantee that block 0 will run before the other blocks in CUDA either.

Comment: I found way to do this with simple while loop...while loop can enforce sync across blocks but I know that it is not good optimization trend ...

Comment: I completely agree with you Roger. Having invested years of my life in supporting CUDA users, I want to make Stack Overflow a great resource for CUDA programmers, and one of my goals is to reduce the unanswered question rate. So @talonmies, I'm going to start cherry-picking your comments and posting them as answers myself. So if you want the reputation points you deserve, I suggest you post answers rather than comments. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__syncthreads()` is a synchronization barrier primitive that only synchronizes threads in the same block.

CUDA has no mechanism for safely synchronizing across thread blocks.

Communication and synchronization between thread blocks is not recommended because it breaks scalability of execution across GPUs with varying numbers of multiprocessors, which is the reason for having thread blocks in the first place.

Comment: It turns out to be serious problem in CUDA. I looked for this a lot and I found paper in IPDPS 10 http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5470477&tag=1. They use custom synchronization methods to achieve synchronization across blocks.

Comment: Lack of global synchronization is not a "serious problem", it is part of the design, for the reasons I described.

Comment: But still it is necessary to have such things on GPU. In PPoPP 13, there is one paper which uses synchronization across blocks and speeds up prefix sum. They have implemented in software but this had provided in hardware then it could been even faster. I totally agree NVIDIA's decision about global sync support, but sometimes having this feature in hardware is useful.

Comment: Note that CUDA _does_ now have a mechanism for inter-block synchronization (but you should still avoid it).